# Data not rendering on child component via parent

Tags: reactjs, rendering, parent-child, react-props

[homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VRfQ.png)

Trying to pass data via get request from sibling to sibling via the parent.

[created a function[passing the function as prop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nytlV.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aY5F.png)

created a function and passing the function as a prop

[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOF4f.png)
when I console.log, database loads but I'm getting 2 errors [1st error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjWcD.png) 
"ackend.js:2655  Warning: A component is changing a controlled input to be uncontrolled. This is likely caused by the value changing from a defined to undefined, which should not happen. Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component. More info: https://reactjs.org/link/controlled-components
at input
at div
at div
at form
at div
at dates /bundle.js:189:74)
[400 bad request error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVk7p.png)
and a post 400 bad request error